# Problem in solving Matrix equation

Tags: equation-solving

can someone help me to find out what is my code problem, I cannot solve the matrix equation

```
m1 = 4;
\[Beta]1 = 0.15;
k1 = 80;
m2 = 5;
\[Beta]2 = 0.02;
k2 = 5000;
M = {{m1, 0}, {0, m2}};
k = {{k1 + k2, -k2}, {-k2, k2}};
Omega = NSolve[Det[k - M \[Omega]^2] == 0 && \[Omega] > 0, \[Omega]][[
  All, 1, 2]]
Time = Table[
  NSolve[T - (2 \[Pi])/Omega[[i]] == 0, T], {i, 1, Length[Omega]}]
mA = k - M Omega[[1]]^2
mC = {{0}, {0}};
mX = Array[\[Phi], {2, 1}]
Solve[mA.mX == mC, Flatten[mX]]
```

And one mor questions, how can I write this matrix, in this code I just have 2 ‘k’ but how I write it for n ‘k’
[image]
I went to the book and he gave me the answers that are shown in the photo of the newly uploaded, I am very, very confused now

[image]

Comment: Did you get any errors?  I got `Det::matsq: Argument -24999920 at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix.` What is this supposed to be: `(m1 0 0 m2)` ? Are you sure you didn't mean `{{m1,0},{0, m2}}`? Same thing for `k` - you should use `{...}` for vectors/lists/matrices, not `(...)`

Comment: it cannot solv and give me this eror: Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Comment: Here are my corrections - I only solve a single omega though: https://pastebin.com/KKXxkg4b

Comment: @flinty That is a warning rather than an error. Anyway, you can avoid it by using `Reduce` instead of `Solve`.

Comment: @flinty You were right, there was a problem copying the code, I fixed it in the post

Comment: But why can't it solve the matrix?

Comment: @ScottConstantine You posted a photo with eastern Arabic numerals. It might help others if you wrote that out in the more common western Arabic and it would make it easier to enter into a notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m1 = 4;
β1 = 3/20;
k1 = 80;
m2 = 5;
β2 = 1/50;
k2 = 5000;
```

The correct way to enter the matrices is

```
M = {{m1, 0}, {0, m2}};
k = {{k1 + k2, -k2}, {-k2, k2}};

(Omega = Solve[Det[k - M*ω^2] == 0 && ω > 0, ω][[All, 1, 
     2]]) // N

(* {2.97406, 47.5516} *)

(Time = 2 Pi/Omega // RootReduce) // N

(* {2.11266, 0.132134} *)

mA = k - M*Omega[[1]]^2 // RootReduce

(* {{540 + 20 Sqrt[50729], -5000}, {-5000, -675 + 25 Sqrt[50729]}} *)
```

Mathematica does not distinguish between row and column vectors. Consequently, `mC` and `mX` should be

```
mC = {0, 0};
mX = Array[ϕ, 2];

eqn = mA.mX == mC;

sol = Solve[eqn, mX]

(* Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

{{ϕ[2] -> -(1/250) (-27 - Sqrt[50729]) ϕ[1]}} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eqn /. sol[[1]] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

For  larger matrices

```
Clear[k];

Format[k[n_]] := Subscript[k, n]

n = 5;
```

The `k` vector

```
kv = Array[k, n]
```

[image]

The `k` matrix

```
(km = (kv + Join[Rest[kv], {0}]) IdentityMatrix[n] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], 1] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[-Rest[kv], -1]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, just another problem when I copy and running the code in the software, it just gets stuck in running mode

Comment: I just copied the code and ran it without any problem. Try restarting Mathematica.

Comment: thank you, now how show result like this {{5080, -5000}, {-5000, 5000}} not like this {{80 + 5000, -5000}, {-5000, 5000}} ,that the code give me

Comment: `mA // N` will convert `mA` to its approximate numeric values.

Comment: I went to the book and he gave me the answers that are shown in the photo of the newly uploaded, I am very, very confused now

Comment: I cannot help you. I have no idea what your notation means.

Comment: The answer to the question is reported in my book {{0.9912, 1}}

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions represented by `\[Phi][2] -> -(1/250) (-27 - Sqrt[50729]) \[Phi][1]`. The result from your book corresponds to setting `\[Phi][2]` equal to `1`. Then `\[Phi][1]` is `250/(27 + Sqrt[50729])` which is approximately `0.991155`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, But what happens to the second part, the code only gives me the first value and not 1 or in the case where according to the book that Omega Equal 47.52The  answer is  {{1, -0.7929}}why the codes do not work

Comment: Presumably there is a constraint or assumption that is not included in the problem statement.

Comment: How can I give a value to k, for example when we write k1=2 does not answer

Comment: it work but give me anser ike this 2+2

Comment: The value of `k1` is `Set` near the beginning of the code `k1 = 80;` If you change this to `k1 = 2;` all subsequent code needs to be reevaluated. If you get a result that **looks** like `2 + 2`, look at the `FullForm` since one or both of the twos is not a number or the `Plus` is `Inactive` or `the expression is being held. If you have any more problems, open a new question showing the code that you are using, and what specifically you are trying to do that is not working.